# ORDER BY most occurring values MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I order this color column from my table

```
color
------ ----
red   |
blue  | 
red   |
green |
blue  |
red   |
yellow|
blue  |
green |
red   |
```

to this

```
color
------ ----
red   |
red   | 
red   |
red   |
blue  |
blue  |
blue  |
green |
green |
yellow|
```

I have tried the following code but it returns just a row of data which is not what I want. I want it to return all values in table

```
SELECT *, COUNT(color) AS count FROM color_table ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, check this out:

```
select b.*
from (
    select color, count(1) cnt
    from color_table
    group by color
) as a
inner join color_table as b
    on a.color = b.color
order by a.cnt desc, a.color
```

Answer (score 2):

Join your table to a query that returns the counter for each color:

```
select c.*
from color_table c inner join (
  select color, count(*) counter  
  from color_table
  group by color
) t on t.color = c.color
order by t.counter desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2hogUZTUZyy4p28oKhuCTw/1).
Or:

```
select c.*
from color_table c
order by (select count(*) from color_table where color = c.color) desc
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2hogUZTUZyy4p28oKhuCTw/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use window function:

```
order by count(*) over (partition by color) desc;
```

Comment: is that the full query?

Comment: @getunstuck . . . No.  It is the `order by` clause.

Comment: he said no wndow functions

Answer (score 1):

You need to group by the color. Otherwise, the count() function will just count all of the records in the table. Like this:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(color) AS count FROM color_table GROUP BY color ORDER BY count DESC
```